# How to run a specific sklearn version?

Tags: scikit-learn, version

On my mac, I installed multiple versions of Sklearn as shown below:

Sklearn 0.19.1

~/anaconda2/pkgs/scikit-learn-0.19.1-py27h9788993_0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn

Sklearn 0.20.0

~/anaconda2/pkgs/scikit-learn-0.20.0-py27h4f467ca_1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn

When starting jupyter, it automatically runs the sklearn 0.20.0. I was wondering whether there is a way to run sklearn 0.19.1.

Thanks a lot,

Jeff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, am not saying it is elegant but is what I would personally try first. `sys.path` is a list of all the places where it goes to import modules, so you first remove any occurrences of the one you don't want and then put in the one you *do* want.

In a cell before you import from sklearn:

```
import sys
syspath = sys.path
indexes = [i for i, s in enumerate(syspath) if 'scikit-learn-0.20.0-py27h4f467ca_1' in s]
for index in indexes:
    syspath.pop(index)
sys.path.insert(0, '~/anaconda2/pkgs/scikit-learn-0.19.1-py27h9788993_0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn')
# now if you import from sklearn, should come from 19
```